# Перестал работать LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... userid IS NULL

Tags: mysql

Был запрос и работал корректно.
Таблица 1:

```
id  title   
1   КомпанияА   
2   КомпанияБ   
3   КомпанияВ
```

Таблица 2:

```
id  companiesid userid  color   
1   1           0       6   
3   1           4       0   
2   2           0       3   
4   3           4       0
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT 
`c`.`color` AS `c--color`, 
`companies`.`id` AS `companies--id`, 
`companies`.`title` AS `companies--title` 
FROM `tbl_companies` AS `companies` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_companies_colors` AS `c` 
ON `c`.`companiesid`=`companies`.`id` 
WHERE  (`c`.`userid`='0' OR `c`.`userid` IS NULL);
```

возвращал:

```
c--color    companies--id   companies--title
6           1               КомпанияА
3           2               КомпанияБ   
NULL        3               КомпанияВ
```

После переезда возвращает только:

```
c--color    companies--id   companies--title
6           1               КомпанияА
3           2               КомпанияБ
```

На обоих серверах (старом и новом):

```
Версия сервера: 5.7.37-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

и

```
sql_mode = '',
```

разница только в том, что старый на выделенном железе, новый в докере. Не могу  понять причину, почему почему перестало работать OR `c`.`userid` IS NULL

Comment: Запрос детерминированный, так что явно где-то что-то различается за пределами запроса, скорее всего исходные данные. Сверяй - как структуры, так и данные. И текст запроса - посимвольно. Проверяй всё. Вплоть до того, в той ли БД выполняешь запрос.

Comment: @akina Спасибо! На большем наборе данных выяснилось, что сам запрос не верный - он возвращал строку
`
c--color    companies--id   companies--title 
NULL        3               КомпанияВ
`
лишь до тех пор, пока не существовало записи другого пользователя в Таблице 2
`
id  companiesid userid  color  
4   3           4       0
`
и тогда встаёт вопрос, как правильно составить запрос, чтобы возвращалась также отсутствующая запись, если для других пользователей она существует.

Answer (score 0):

Был неправильно составлен запрос, правильно:

```
SELECT 
`c`.`color` AS `c--color`, 
`companies`.`id` AS `companies--id`, 
`companies`.`title` AS `companies--title`
FROM `tbl_companies` AS `companies`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_companies_colors` AS `c` 
ON `c`.`companiesid`=`companies`.`id` AND (`c`.`userid`='0' OR `c`.`userid` IS NULL);
```